# java calling method in other class doesn't recognize changed variables

Tags: java, class, methods

I am working on developing a simple text-based RPG game. Currently I am working on a system to save the player's progress to a text file that can be reopened and loaded from. This is where I encountered my problem. When calling a getter that returns the value of a single variable in a class, the getter returns the default value of 0 that I have set and doesn't recognize that I changed the value of it throughout the game.

Character Class

```
public class Character
{
    private int _strength = 0; //initialize the strength variable

    public Character() //constructor
    {  }

    public void setStrength(int strength)  //sets the value of strength
    { _strength = strength; }

    public int getStrength() //gets the value of strength
    { return _strength; }
}
```

If I create a Character variable in the main game and assign strength a value with the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Character character = new Character(); //initializes the Character variable

    character.setStrength(5); //sets the character's strength to 5
    System.out.println(character.getStrength()); //prints out 5 as expected.
}
```

If I go to a different class without the main function in it, such as:

```
public class SaveSystem
{
    private Character character = new Character(); //exactly the same as above...

    public SaveSystem()
    {  }

    public void saveGame()
    {
        //just to test the methods used earlier
        System.out.println(character.getStrength()));
    }
}
```

I should be able to go back to that class with the main function and say:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Character character = new Character(); //initializes the Character variable
    SaveSystem save = new SaveSystem();

    character.setStrength(5); //sets the character's strength to 5
    save.saveGame(); //containing nothing but the character.getStrength() method
}
```

and have it print the same value of 5. However, it prints out the value of 0 that is assigned when the strength variable is initialized in the character class. If I change the default value of strength in the character class as shown:

```
public class Character
{ private int _strength = 5; //initialize the strength variable }
```

then the save.saveGame method in the main class will print out 5. I have been stuck on this for a few days now, and Google has not been helpful in the slightest despite my efforts.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Both of you are correct. I'm not sure which one to accept as correct on here, though. Thank you so much for your help! I've been stuck for a while on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are creating a new character when you create your save object, rather than passing in the character to save. You might try something like this:

```
public class SaveSystem
{
    public SaveSystem()
    {  }

    public void saveGame(Character character)
    {
        //just to test the methods used earlier
        System.out.println(character.getStrength()));
    }
}
```

Then you'd call it like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Character character = new Character(); //initializes the Character variable
    SaveSystem save = new SaveSystem();

    character.setStrength(5); //sets the character's strength to 5
    save.saveGame(character); //containing nothing but the character.getStrength() method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SaveSystem` is supposed to save the existing `Character` objects, not to create brand new ones by itself and save them.

So remove the creation in `SaveSystem`, and pass your `Character` to the save method.

```
public class SaveSystem
{


    public SaveSystem()
    {  }

    public void saveGame(Character character)
    {
        //just to test the methods used earlier
        System.out.println(character.getStrength()));
    }
}
```

And

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Character character = new Character(); //initializes the Character variable
    SaveSystem save = new SaveSystem();

    character.setStrength(5); //sets the character's strength to 5
    save.saveGame(character); 
}
```